# Meaning of $ sign in ljmpl

Tags: assembly

Could someone explain the difference between the two following lines of x86 assembler?

- `ljmpl $KERNEL64_CS, $64f`
- `ljmpl $KERNEL64_CS, 64f`

(The `64f` above is actually a reference to a `64:` label on the next line of assembler code.)

Comment: I suspect the former offsets the jump by the value stored at memory address 64f, while the latter offsets the jump by 64f.  Not posting as an answer because this is actually a guess. ;-)  Consult your assembler documentation.

Comment: Did you already look at the disassembly? Maybe it is equal. In fact there is only one "ljmpl" instruction on the x86. I tested with GNU assembler: The second line gives me an error!